# How to put a dot in windows Phone calendar's date

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing a windows phone application,here I am  getting the XML data from .net web-service. web method returns list of dates ,only these dates I need to highlight on calendar by putting a dot or color,apart from this I can able to pass selected date as input to another web method but unable to highlight list of dates simultaneously. below is the code I tried for it.

XElement xmlNews = XElement.Parse(e.Result.ToString());

```
        Cal.DataContext = from item in xmlNews.Descendants("Events")
                           select new Institute()
                           {
                               Adress = item.Element("Event_From").Value
                           };
<wpControls:Calendar 
            x:Name="Cal" MonthChanged="Cal_MonthChanged"  DatesSource="{Binding}" SelectedDate="{Binding Adress}"
            MonthChanging="Cal_MonthChanging"
            SelectionChanged="Cal_SelectionChanged"
            DateClicked="Cal_DateClicked"
            EnableGestures="True" Margin="2,-5,0,21" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using the calendar provided in the [Windows Phone Controls 7](http://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/)  library from codeplex.
To customize the calendar for your needs, you will need to implement a converter and make it implement the IDateToBrushConverter. This interface provides a single Method Convert that will be called by the calendar to ask for which brush you want to use as a background or foreground for the specified calendar case. The trick here is that you specify the a global instance of the converter and supply it with the dates returned from the backend web service, say for example inject it in the constructor or specify it as a static method (which I don't like) and then in your Convert method,  you check whether the calendar case's date is within the specified list or not, if so you return the brush you want depending on your needs
Here is an example:

```
public class CalendarColorBackgroundConverter : IDateToBrushConverter 
{
    // ctor
    public CalendarColorBackgroundConverter(IEnumerable<DateTime> datesToHighlight)
    {
         this.DatesToHighlight = datesToHighlight;
    }

    IEnumerable<DateTime> DatesToHighlight {get; private set;}

    // some predefined brushes.
    //static SolidColorBrush transparentBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    static SolidColorBrush whiteColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    static SolidColorBrush selectedColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
    static SolidColorBrush todayColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 74, 128, 1));
    static SolidColorBrush Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 108, 180, 195));

    public Brush Convert(DateTime currentCalendarCaseDate, bool isSelected, Brush defaultValue, BrushType brushType)
    {
        var highlightDate = this.DatesToHighlight.Any(d => d.Year == currentCalendarCaseDate.Year && d.Month == currentCalendarCaseDateMonth.Month &&
                      d.Day == currentCalendarCaseDate.Day);
        if (brushType == BrushType.Background) 
        {
            if (highlightDate) // background brush color when the calendar case is selected
                return todayColorBrush;
            else
                return whiteColorBrush;
        } 
        else
        {
            if (highlightDate)
                return whiteColorBrush;
            return Foreground;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.